# How to do Github GraphQL Search for code?

Tags: github, search, graphql, github-api

All the Github GraphQL API doc/tutorials that I saw are only doing “`type: REPOSITORY`” searches. 
And such `type:` doesn't have an option for *code search*.

So, is it possible to do Github GraphQL Search for code? If so, please use the example of searching within `language:Go` and with keyword `tucnak/telebot`. Thx.